# Windows 8: Handling the event when SuggestionsRequested is empty

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I need to handle the event where the searchpane's textbox is empty.

`SearchPaneSuggestionsRequested` event is not raised when typing backspace until a textbox is empty.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `TextBox.TextChanged` and always check `TextBox.Text == string.Empty()`. 
 Hope it's help.